# Method signature change in Eclipse gives error

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, java-8, eclipse-mars

I have two inner classes and a method:

```
protected <A extends Obj1> void a(P<A> p)
{}

private static class P<Z extends Obj1>
{}

private static class Obj1
{}
```

It's compiling fine, but when I try in Eclipse <s>Mars</s> to change the method `a`'s signature by giving it a second attribute this way

[image]

gives the following error:

> Bound mismatch: The type A is not a valid substitute for the bounded
>   parameter <Z extends Test.Obj1> of the type Test.P<Z>

Now actually I have two questions about this. Why is this behavioural difference and what did I do wrong?

Strangely when I modify manually `a` to this:

```
protected <A extends Obj1> void a(P<? extends A> p)
{}
```

and try to change the signature the previously decribed manner I don't get that error. I have a feeling that this may be a bug either in Java or Eclipse, but don't really know where to start seaching. <s>so I give you their versions too if it helps:</s>

- Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2)
- Java 1.8.0.77

**UPDATE:**

So I've tried more different versions of Eclipse and Java 8, but the result is the same.

Comment: A) you could try some eclipse forums; this is *very* specific, I doubt that you will get much help here B) try either updating your Mars ... or directly test your problem on Neon.

Comment: Not sure I understand right thiss. The capture show that A is not "defined" as `<A extends Obj1>`. It is showed as `protected void a(P<? extends A> p)` so I guess this screen doesn't support genericity.

Comment: I’d consider that a minor Eclipse UI issue, as, when you click on “continue”, the refactoring completes as expected, without any error in the result.